# Can your's ever be used?

Tags: grammaticality, word-usage, saxon-genitive

I have a specific sentence in which I feel inclined to use "your's" but in not sure if it's correct. Then sentence is:

*"Every story has a beginning - This is your's."*

What "your's" stand for here is simply *"this is your story's beginning"* but to spell it out like that doesn't create the same feeling.

Albeit, is this a correct usage of "your's"?

Edit: This is not a duplicate of "Yours vs your's" as I'm asking for a situation in which "yours" can't be used since it would mean their beginning, not their stories' beginning.

Comment: Your's can't be correct.  Firstly, "your" is not a noun and therefore cannot be inflected to have the possessive case of a noun.  Secondly, personal pronouns have their own distinct possessive forms.

Comment: So what should be used instead to make it clear that it's their stories' beginning I'm talking about?

Comment: Just as you would say "This is hers", you would say "This is yours".

Comment: But as I stated in my edit, that would mean it's theirs beginning, not their stories' beginning.

Comment: "You" is the pronoun for the second person.  This implies a person.  A book or a story is not a person and so the pronoun "you" is not appropriate for any case.  When you say "you" or "your" or "yours", you are implicitly referring to someone.  If you want to talk about the book, you'll need to craft your sentence differently.  Consider "Every story has a beginning.  This is its beginning."

Comment: There is nothing wrong with saying "Every story has a beginning - This is yours."  It is readily understood to mean "... your story's beginning."

Comment: Agreed.  The interpretation is "Every story has a beginning - This is your [story's beginning]."  An alternative is "Every story has a beginning.  This is it."  In this latter, the beginning of the story has the emphasis, whereas "your story" is the emphasis of the former.

Comment: Would you say `this is my's`? `this is your's` would be just as wrong. To avoid the misunderstanding, add more words; `this is your story's beginning`

Comment: This web page has a concise review of the cases of personal pronouns: http://www.englisch-hilfen.de/en/grammar/pronomen.htm

Comment: *Their* is not a possessive pronoun like *hers*; it’s a **possessive *determiner*** like *her*.  *Their**s*** is the **possessive *pronoun*** like *mine* or *her**s***.  You can no more use *theirs* as a determiner than you can use *hers* for one.